# Chemical elements spelled out are not capitalised but what about Natural Gas?

Tags: nouns, capitalization

A quick google shows that natural gas is generally capitalised whereas the rule for chemical elements seems to be that they are not. I am writing a text that includes Natural Gas (I cannot replace that with methane) and chemical elements such as helium. I find it odd to capitalise Natural Gas and not helium.

What is the correct way to spell Natural Gas?

Comment: Because "Natural Gas" is not just any natural gas. Let me know if you need more detailed explanation.

Comment: "*A quick google shows that natural gas is generally capitalised*" Your Google must be different from mine.

Comment: You only capitalize it if you're making money off of it.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_gas) writes it in lower-case.

All the dictionaries I have searched write it in lower-case.

(That would be [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/natural%20gas), [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/natural-gas), [the Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/natural+gas) and [the Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/natural-gas).)

The only cases you would write it in capital letters would be in a title or name, e.g. the Natural Gas Association.

Comment: Add [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_gas) to the list.